# how to improve plant/stem texture?

Tags: texturing

Any suggestions on how to make this stem look more realistic?   It just looks so uninteresting right now and I'm not experienced enough to know where to begin.  I've tried grabbing random greenish textures online and mapping on but it looks like garbage.  I want to get more of those vertical stripes going on and the darker edges..

[image: ideal]

[image: current model]

Comment: You need to create some vertical stripes, to do so unwrap your mesh and use a Noise Texture that you'll stretch?

Comment: how do I get the darker color on the edges

Answer (score 1):

You could do that:

[image]

Which is a gradient of green on Z thanks to a *Separate XYZ* node, and a *Noise Texture* as bump. You'll first need to unwrap the mesh, for example with the *Cylinder Projection* option:

[image]